# Getting JSON from an API written in service, it has to be converted to table rows

Tags: angular

This is my component ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GetTransactionService } from '../../../service/getTransaction/get-transaction.service';
import { Router, Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-transactions',
  templateUrl: './transactions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./transactions.component.css']
})
export class TransactionsComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private _data: GetTransactionService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getTransactionDtls = function () {
      let transactionResponse = this._data.getTransactionDtls();
  }

}
```

This is my service ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { RouterModule, Routes, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Headers, RequestOptions, Request, RequestMethod, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GetTransactionService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    configUrl = "https://10.1.18.56:7070/eps/epsconsole/getTransactions?Authorization=f9c6c84b-d980-47e5-bfaa-5292d3d89805&Content-Type=application/json&systemId=FZHolidays&userName=manoj.g.ext";



    getTransactionDtls = function () {
        //let transactionHeaders = new Headers({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'true', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'systemId': 'FZHolidays', 'Authorization': '7e2af87e-d9b8-419e-a689-80fb561aae4a', 'userName':'manoj.g.ext'});

        let transactionHeaders = new Headers();

        //transactionHeaders.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "true");
        //transactionHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
        //transactionHeaders.set("systemId", "FZHolidays");
        //transactionHeaders.set("Authorization", "f0e3383b-21a1-48c8-992e-20f5eacb4b60");
        //transactionHeaders.set("userName", "manoj.g.ext");

        //const transactionHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
        //    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "true",
        //    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        //    'systemId': 'FZHolidays',
        //    'Authorization': '444a2834-80b6-4699-bb19-b20f0d2d42cb',
        //    'userName': 'manoj.g.ext'
        //});

        //transactionHeaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "true");
        //transactionHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");       
        //transactionHeaders.append("systemId", "FZHolidays");
        //transactionHeaders.append("Authorization", "f2dcc933-4c8c-4563-a4db-6388431b3caa");
        //transactionHeaders.append("userName", "manoj.g.ext");

        const bodys = {
            "orderId": null,
            "systemId": "FZHolidays",
            "paymentId": null,
            "entityId": null,
            "currency": null,
            "paymentMethod": null,
            "status": null,
            "startDate": "11-06-2018",
            "endDate": "11-06-2018"
        };

        let options: RequestOptionsArgs = new RequestOptions({ headers: transactionHeaders });


        //const req = new Request(options);

        let responseJSON; 
        return this.http.post(this.configUrl, bodys, options).subscribe(
            success => {
                console.log(success);
                responseJSON = success;
                this.populateOrder(success);
            }, error => {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
    }

    populateOrder = function (response) {

    }

}
```

This is my HTML

```
    <table class="table table-hover" id="orderTbl">
      <thead>
        <tr class="tblHeadColor">
          <th>Order ID</th>
          <th>Order Date</th>
          <th>Modified Date</th>
          <th>System Id</th>
          <th>Entity Id</th>
          <th>Payment Id</th>
          <th>Payment Method</th>
          <th>Currency</th>
          <th>Order Amount</th>
          <th>Order Status</th>
          <th>Refund Amount</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor ="let row of responseJSON">
          <td>{{row.orderId}}</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>Visa</td>
          <td>23343444</td>
          <td></td>
          <td>Authorized</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>


      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Help me out how to crate tr with received JSON, also tell me how to access component variable inside view.
The JSON I'm getting is from an API and it is not static, so tr should be formed as soon as JSON is received.
Any help will be of great use

Comment: Where are you stuck?
Are you already getting the response from an API and just want to display or you are not even getting the response?

Comment: I believe combining both the answers below(Mine && Sachin's answer) will get you going...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

subscribe to the service from component instead of service. In the service just return the observable.

service

```
 getTransactionDtls = function() {

     let transactionHeaders = new Headers();

     const bodys = {
         "orderId": null,
         "systemId": "FZHolidays",
         "paymentId": null,
         "entityId": null,
         "currency": null,
         "paymentMethod": null,
         "status": null,
         "startDate": "11-06-2018",
         "endDate": "11-06-2018"
     };

     let options: RequestOptionsArgs = new RequestOptions({
         headers: transactionHeaders
     });
     return this.http.post(this.configUrl, bodys, options)
 }
```

in the component make a public property `responseJSON` and assign values inside the subscription

```
export class TransactionsComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private _data: GetTransactionService) {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    public responseJSON;

    getTransactionDtls = function() {
        this._data.getTransactionDtls().subscribe(
            success => {
                console.log(success);
                this.responseJSON = success
            }, error => {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );;
    }

}
```

Comment: subscribed from component but public responseJSON inside function is giving couldn`t find name error

Comment: change `getTransactionDtls = function()` to `getTransactionDtls(){`

Comment: do the same for other methods

Comment: It worked but what is the diff between getTransactionDtls = function() and getTransactionDtls(){

Comment: this is the standard way od creating a function in angular. in ES6 we are not using the `function` keyword. we have arrow notation. so try to use that from now on

Comment: Also can`t we access data directly from service

Comment: Thanks a lot, should I include something for using es6 in my project, so far I was using typescript

Comment: you can. but then again you have to send it back to component or component needs to call your service again. because template can only access component variables

Comment: typescript support mordern es6. just check out the typescript official page

Comment: Hi can you convert the above function to arrow notation, I could use it as an example..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have the response from the API and assuming that you have it in the form of Array of objects:

```
// You have the response here as:
this.dataSet = res.data;

// This is how you will use it in your view
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let data of dataSet">
      <td>{{ data.one }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.two }}</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>

// But the view does not know when to update the view, So you have use *ngIf so as 
// the data is received you will show the results
<tbody *ngIf="dataSet">
```

Let me know if it's helpful or you are looking for something else.

Comment: Yes I can see that and by view I mean HTML file...
let say in your .ts file you get the data in some variable called dataSet, then you can access it in your HTML file by using string interpolation {{ dataSet }}

Read the above answer again...

Comment: The problem is can I take data from service to html directly

Comment: If you are getting the data in a separate service then you have to access it in your component's .ts file and then access it in your HTML

I don't think that you can access the response from a service directly into your HTML file

Comment: You have to inject your service in your .ts file and then you have to store it in some variable and then you have to use in your HTML file using string interpolation...

Comment: Were you able to do it?

Comment: You can mark the answer as right if it helped... and you are welcome